# A way to search for words in Google sheet and highlight rows containing them

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I started from a code I found working, but am stuck in the application of it. I have a list of words and if they find match in a sheet file I should colour the background of the cell containing it (or the row containing it). But as I get the values using the SHTvalues.map it seems it cannot be directly used as it produce an array of results.
Below the code.

thank you!

```
 var findText = "FIRST WORD";
 var findText2='SECOND WORD';

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('23PzZzz23442321212i1rJDnasXD');
var CurrSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('sheetname');
var SHTvalues = CurrSheet.createTextFinder(findText).findAll();
var result = SHTvalues.map(r => ({row: r.getRow(), col: r.getColumn()}));
var SHTvalues = CurrSheet.createTextFinder(findText2).findAll();
var result2 = SHTvalues.map(r => ({row: r.getRow(), col: r.getColumn()}));
console.log(result)
console.log(result2)
sheet.getSheetByName('sheetname').getRange(result).setBackground('yellow');
sheet.getSheetByName('sheetname').getRange(result2).setBackground('yellow');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the Range class returned by `getRange()` always covers a rectangular region. It can't return an arbitrary list of scattered cells. What you're probably looking for is [getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations).

```
var findText = "FIRST WORD";
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('23PzZzz23442321212i1rJDnasXD');
var CurrSheet = sheet.getSheetByName('sheetname');
var SHTvalues = CurrSheet.createTextFinder(findText).findAll();
var result = SHTvalues.map(r => r.getA1Notation());
console.log(result)
var rangeList = sheet.getSheetByName('sheetname').getRangeList(result);
for (var range of rangeList.getRanges()) {
    range.setBackground('yellow');
}
```

**UPDATE**

That said, it probably makes more sense to use conditional formatting instead of a script, as doubleunary mentioned in their answer, unless you want the change to be permanent or some other complex reason. I will still keep this answer up, as it answers the original question.

Comment: thanks, I was integrating this with other functions. I need to email those rows after and that's why I did'nt check normal functions.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably make more sense to do this with Google Sheets built-in [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413).

To highlight cells that contain one of the words, use a conditional formatting custom formula rule like this:

`=regexmatch(A1, "FIRST WORD|SECOND WORD")`

To highlight *rows* where any cell in columns `A:Z` contains one of the words, use a conditional formatting custom formula rule like this:

`=arrayformula( sum( n( regexmatch(trim($A1:$Z1), "FIRST WORD|SECOND WORD") ) ) )`

To answer your question, the `Sheet.getRange()` method accepts `A1` type references, `R1C1` type references, and numeric row and column indices with optional numRows and numColumns arguments. It does not accept the kind of arrays of objects that you are using: `[{ row: 1, col: 1 }, { row: 1, col: 2 }, { row: 2, col: 1 }]`.

Comment: Thank you, very clear!

Answer (score 0):

**Searching for an array of words**

With muliple background colors.

```
function myfunk() {
  const words = ['one', 'two', 'three']; //add words to array
  const colors = ['yellow', 'green', 'red', 'blue', 'orange'];//add more colors if necessary
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//change openById if you wish
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');//change sheet name
  words.forEach((w, i) => {
    var vs = sh.createTextFinder(w).findAll();
    vs.forEach(r => {
      r.setBackground(colors[i % colors.length]);//r is the range and there can be more words than colors if you don't mind repeating them
    });
  });
}
```

**References:**

[creatTextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#createTextFinder(String))

Image:

[image]